# Multiple Facebook Applications as Identity Provider for AWS Cognito Federated Identities

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-web-services, facebook-apps, amazon-cognito

We are using AWS Cognito (Federated Identities) in order to provide login via facebook and google+.

We are facing the following challenge. Our company is providing different apps, that interact with each other, so that we would like to have authenticated users to have one identity inside of one cognito identity pool. And to make use of the sync store cross apps.

For cognito you can only choose one audience (client-id/app-id) for each IdP, when using the AWS console. It would make sense for us, to associate many facebook audiences and google+ audiences with that one cognito setup.

We figured out how to setup many google+ audiences, by creating google+ as IdP via IAM. Which works perfectly fine for us. 
We are struggling to figure out a way how to configure many facebook audience via IAM-IdP or any other way.

Well, facebook is no open-id-connect provider, and that seems to be the issue. But I kind of don't want to accept this.

**Does one of you know how to configure multiple facebook apps to be associated with one cognito identity pool. Workaround are very welcome.**

One additional information: It would be OK for us to use one global facebook app, e.g. 'OurCompany - Network', that would do the trick. The blocker for this is, that it would block us from doing facebook-campaigns with installation tracking. If you know a workaround for this, is also a welcome solution.

Comment: how did u solved this? What is ur final approach?

Answer (score 1):

I did this by using multiple pools, and then allowing both pools at the role level. That means my Trust Relationships for that role look like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": [
            "<first cognito pool>",
            "<second cognito pool>"
          ]
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try this out. Maybe you can help me out with two further questions regarding this:
1) if one user logs in via facebook to both pools, will he have 2 different cogntio ids?
2) if one user logs in via facebook to both pools, will he have 1 cognito sync store / or does he know how to access both?

Comment: 1) Yes, each login to a Cognito pool will end up with a different identity.  
2) No, two separate stores. Not sure why you'd want to support that kind of behavior, but I'd suggest creating some unified identifier for shared data, instead.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Would be great if you'd accept this answer, @Torben or let me know why it's not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to use [Developer Authenticated Identities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html). You will need to validate the Facebook token yourself in this case.